# Python - Starting a thread kills all threads using sys.exit()

Tags: python, multithreading

Im having issue with threading. Basically when I do a `threading.Thread(target=self.d3JpdGVDU1Y(payload)).start()` which means it will create a new thread with a target and params for that function.

My problem is that when I do a sys.exit() on that thread, it stops the whole script even though it is supposed to continue to run the main(): function since we are just creating a new thread for the different functions.

```py
def main():
    # Discord send
    if self.discordWebhook:
        threading.Thread(
            target=sendtoWebhook.c2VuZFRvRGlzY29yZA(self, self.discordWebhook, payload)).start()

    # Send to CSV write
    threading.Thread(target=self.d3JpdGVDU1Y(payload)).start()

--------------------------------

class sendtoWebhook:

    def c2VuZFRvRGlzY29yZA(self, webhook, payload):
        response = requests.post('{}/slack'.format(webhook), json=discord)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Sent to discord!")
            sys.exit()

        elif response.status_code == 429:
            print("Failed printing")
            sys.exit()
```

What it supposed to do is to kill the thread for the sendtoWebhook function and not the all using sys.exit() or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The thread will terminate when it returns from the function `c2VuZFRvRGlzY29yZA`.

Comment: but if I do sys.exit() inside `c2VuZFRvRGlzY29yZA` that just stops the main() function to do the second threading.start aswell @Booboo

Comment: You don’t run the function in a thread. You run the function and pass its return value to a thread-which doesn’t exist because the function sends SystemExit which kills everything waiting for its value, including the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code never starts a thread.

In `main()`, you do this:

```
Thread(target=func_that_calls_sys_exit(foo, bar), ...)
```

when you mean to do this:

```
Thread(target=func_that_calls_sys_exit, args=(foo, bar), ...)
```

The former *invokes* the method before any thread is created, intending to pass its return value to the `Thread` constructor's `target` parameter.  That invocation of course raises a `SystemExit`, thus terminating your process before any threads can be created.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to close the execution of the thread. (Can't verify by commenting because of low reps).

`sys.exit()` is used to exit from Python, not from a thread. This means that if you call `sys.exit()` you will close the whole execution.

Just replace `sys.exit()` with `thread.exit()` and that should work fine for you. `thread.exit()` is used to close the execution of a thread.

Comment: ``sys.exit()`` raises ``SystemExit`` *in the current thread*. It does not affect other threads. Per the docs: "Since ``exit()`` ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process *when called from the main thread*, and the exception is not intercepted."

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "It will only exit the **process**". A thread is not a process. A thread can be called as a sub-unit of process.

Comment: That's why ``sys.exit()`` will exit the process (i.e. Python) only *when called from [that process'] main thread*.

Comment: Note that you can test this directly by calling ``sys.exit`` in a Thread, e.g. via ``threading.Thread(target=sys.exit).start()``.